# How to compile bind to extension methods in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I know I've done this before, but I cannot find the reference I had before.
If I have a class defined like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace1 {
    public class MyClass {}
}
```

And then an extension method and some other static method defined like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace2 {
    public static class MyClassExt {
        public static string GetExtVal(this MyClass myClass) => "an extension val";
        public static string GetStaticVal(bool arg) => "a static val";
    }
}
```

I know I can bind to the static function by first adding a reference to the namespaces

```
    xmlns:ns1="using:Namespace1"
    xmlns:ns2="using:Namespace2"
```

And then calling it like this

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="ns1:MyClass">
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ns2:MyClassExt.GetStaticVal(x:True)}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

But, how can I bind to the extension method?

I've tried this:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="ns1:MyClass">
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ns2:MyClassExt.GetExtVal(ns1:MyClass)}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

And this

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="ns1:MyClass">
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ns2:MyClassExt.GetExtVal()}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

But neither of those will compile.

I keep looking [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/function-bindings) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth), but I'm not seeing what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an extra set of parentheses does the trick:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="ns1:MyClass">
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ns2:MyClassExt.GetExtVal((ns1:MyClass))}" />
</DataTemplate>
```